# canvas stopped animation?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, android-canvas

I'm building game in HTML5 for Android browsers, after some times the canvas stopped animation suddenly without any reason ?

```
function updateAnimation()
{
    context.clear = true; // makes the canvas clear itself on every frame           
    context.save();
    context.clearRect(0,0,ourGameCanvas.width,ourGameCanvas.height);
    context.drawImage(bg_img,0,0,ourGameCanvas.width,ourGameCanvas.height);     
    context.restore();
}

function startupTouchEvents()
{
    ourGameCanvas.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
    ourGameCanvas.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
}

function handleStart(evt)
{
    evt.preventDefault();       
    var touches = evt.changedTouches;
}

function handleMove(evt)
{
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```

When I touch the screen many times the animation stooped for NO reason !!!

Any idea ?

Comment: Many objects moving in the screen and hide it when touched.

Comment: Not with the code you've posted

Comment: have you checked browser logs?